# hide a record according to status

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I need to hide a record if the status is == 'Terminado'.

It is done with an if condition, but I don't know how to apply it

[image]

blade.php

```
  <tbody>
                                    @foreach($registros as $registro)
                                       @if($registro->sucursal == Auth::user()->sucursal) 
                                       @if($registro->empleado == Auth::user()->tipo) 
                             
                               
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{$registro->cliente}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$registro->tipo}}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="progress br-30">

                                                @if($registro->estado == 'Ingresado') 
                                                <div class="progress-bar br-30 bg-primary" role="progressbar" style="width: 20%" aria-valuenow="67" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                                @elseif($registro->estado == 'Envío de Prespuesto') 
                                                 <div class="progress-bar br-30 bg-secondry" role="progressbar" style="width: 40%" aria-valuenow="67" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                                 @elseif($registro->estado == 'Anticipo Recibido') 
                                                 <div class="progress-bar br-30 bg-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 60%" aria-valuenow="67" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                                 @elseif ($registro->estado == 'En Reparación') 
                                                 <div class="progress-bar br-30 bg-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 80%" aria-valuenow="67" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                                 @elseif ($registro->estado == 'Terminado') 
                                                 <div class="progress-bar br-30 bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="67" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                                 @elseif ($registro->estado == 'Cancelado') 
                                                 <div class="progress-bar br-30 bg-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="67" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>


                                                @endif

                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>{{$registro->estado}}</td>
                                            <td>{{ ($registro->created_at->format('d-m-Y')) }}</td>
                                            <td> @if($registro->presupuesto == null) No Aplicado @else ${{$registro->presupuesto}} @endif</td>
                                            <td class="text-center">
                                                <div class="dropdown custom-dropdown">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-more-horizontal"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="1"></circle><circle cx="19" cy="12" r="1"></circle><circle cx="5" cy="12" r="1"></circle></svg>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink1">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('detalle', $registro)}}">Ver</a>
                                                        <a href="{{route('editar', $registro)}}" class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Actualizar</a>
                                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);">Borrar</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        @elseif($registro->estado == 'Terminado') 
                                        
                                        @endif
                                        @endif
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
```

the foreach should not show if the status field is == **Terminado**

but if it has no finished status, if it should show record

controller:

```
 public function registros(){

        if (Auth::guest()) return redirect('/login');

        $data = [
            'category_name' => 'datatable',
            'page_name' => 'multiple_tables',
        'has_scrollspy' => 0,
        'scrollspy_offset' => '',
        'fechax' => Carbon::now(),

        ];

      

        $registros = \App\Models\Registro::All();
       
        return view('pages.tables.table_dt_multiple_tables',compact('registros'))->with($data);
   


    }
```

attached blade controller
attached blade controller
**help pls**

Comment: could you also [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68116995/edit) the code of the controller where you call the view and pass the data to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `continue` inside the loop to skip the current item.

```
@foreach($registros as $registro)
    @if ($registro->estado == 'Terminado')
        @continue
    @endif

    <!-- Rest of the template -->
@endforeach
```

However, I'd rather handle that in the controller.

```php
class RegistroController extends Controller
{
    public function registros(){
        if (Auth::guest()) return redirect('/login');
        $data = [
            'category_name' => 'datatable',
            'page_name' => 'multiple_tables',
            'has_scrollspy' => 0,
            'scrollspy_offset' => '',
            'fechax' => Carbon::now(),
        ];
        $registros = \App\Models\Registro::where('estado', '<>', 'Terminado')->get();

        return view('pages.tables.table_dt_multiple_tables', compact('registros'))->with($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in your controller, where you are making the query:

```php
Registro::where('estado', '!=' , 'Terminado')->get();
```

PS: I assume your model name is `Registro`

Answer (score 0):

If the record is status 'Terminado', you want to exclude from the foreach only?
blade

```
@foreach($registros as $registro)
 @if($registro->status != 'Terminado')
   //.....
```

or in the controller you can exclude this rows when you query the db.
There is another approach for ends status and for others, that depends of your requirements, and is SoftDeletes. Maybe using it could help you to exclude from your queries if this finished status is unnecessary in the most of cases or just in puntual cases you can retrieve this data.